# Pipe multiple tagged messages to program from within mutt

Tags: email, tags, pipe, tagging, mutt

I understand how to pipe the contents of a single message through `|`. Also I understand how to tag messages in multiple different ways, as described in the help accessible through `?`.

What I don't know:

1. How can you pipe the contents of a list of tagged messages to a program?
2. Is there a way to pipe a single message to a single program call?
3. Is there also a way to pipe the concatenated contents of all messages to a single program call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> pipe-message (default: |)
>
> Asks for an external Unix command and pipes the current or tagged message
>      (s) to it. The variables $pipe_decode, $pipe_split, $pipe_sep and $wait_key
>      control the exact behavior of this function.

So, depending on the 3 settings (`$pipe_decode`, `$pipe_split` and `$pipe_sep`), you can accomplish your use cases.

Answer (score 0):

actually, on my mutt (1.10.1), the | pipes ONLY the current message, not all tagged. I tink, thats the same problem the thread starter had

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).